# Error trying to re-deploy zip file of Lambda function

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am trying to create a script to copy some lambda functions and re-upload them as test copies with a few line changes.

I can successfully download a zip file from a function, and I can create a new function using that zip file

The trouble is when I try to open the file, transfer the code into a new zip file, and re-upload it. I eventually want to edit the code in the process but I find that even opening and re-zipping it introduces the error (so I have narrowed it down that far)

Here is my code:

```
import requests
import boto3
import zipfile

client = boto3.client('lambda')

def download_lambda(function_arn):
    tmp_dir = ''

    arn = function_arn
    arn_parts = arn.split(':')
    func_name = arn_parts[6]

    func_details = client.get_function(FunctionName=function_arn)
    zip_file = tmp_dir + func_name + '.zip'
    url = func_details['Code']['Location']

    r = requests.get(url)
    with open(zip_file, "wb") as code:
        code.write(r.content)

def aws_file(zipname):
    with open(zipname, 'rb') as file_data:
        bytes_content = file_data.read()
    return bytes_content

def lambda_creator(function_name, configs):
    response = client.create_function(
        Code={
            'ZipFile': aws_file(function_name + '.zip')
        },
        FunctionName="TEST_" + function_name,
        Role=config['Role'],
        Handler=config['Handler'],
        Description=config['Description'],
        Timeout=config['Timeout'],
        MemorySize=config['MemorySize'],
        Runtime=config['Runtime']
    )
    return response


download_lambda("arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:965541273308:function:$function")
archive = zipfile.ZipFile(f"{function}.zip", 'r')

# read in the function code
function_code = archive.read('lambda_function.py')
function_code = function_code.decode('utf-8')
# Change some things in the function code
with open("lambda_function.py", "w") as f:
    f.write(function_code)

# zip the function code
archive = zipfile.ZipFile(f"TEST_{function}.zip", 'w')
archive.write("lambda_function.py")

# get the config of the original function
response = client.get_function(FunctionName=function)
config = response['Configuration']

# This works:
lambda_creator(function, config)

# But this gives an error:
lambda_creator("TEST_" + function, config)
```

This gives the error: "botocore.errorfactory.InvalidParameterValueException: An error occurred (InvalidParameterValueException) when calling the CreateFunction operation: Could not unzip uploaded file. Please check your file, then try to upload again."

I have tried uploading the file to S3 first, and also doing it through the CLI, no luck in any case.

I have found some similar posts around this issue, for example:
https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/488

I am trying to apply these solutions here but I end up just going in circles. Wondering if anyone can spot what the problem is.

I realize I am doing an extra step by actually creating a zip file; I think I should be able to just pass the contents as a byte string. I still have the same error doing this, though.

Comment: Unsure if this is the problem, but you're not closing the zipfile. Typically you would use a context manager e.g. `with ZipFile('test.zip', 'w') as z: z.write("app.py")` so that you don't have to close it explicitly.

Comment: Frame challenge: I don't know if python has any DI frameworks, but you can always roll your own by putting your "changed" code to a separate file and import it conditionally, depending on an environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check out [this example scenario in the AWS SDK Code Examples library](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-library/latest/ug/lambda_example_lambda_Scenario_GettingStartedFunctions_section.html) that demonstrates creating, uploading, updating, and re-uploading a Lambda function in Python. If you clone the repo, you can run this example for yourself. In particular, the function that packages the code for upload looks like this:

```
@staticmethod
def create_deployment_package(source_file, destination_file):
    """
    Creates a Lambda deployment package in .zip format in an in-memory buffer. This
    buffer can be passed directly to Lambda when creating the function.

    :param source_file: The name of the file that contains the Lambda handler
                        function.
    :param destination_file: The name to give the file when it's deployed to Lambda.
    :return: The deployment package.
    """
    buffer = io.BytesIO()
    with zipfile.ZipFile(buffer, "w") as zipped:
        zipped.write(source_file, destination_file)
    buffer.seek(0)
    return buffer.read()


 def update_function_code(self, function_name, deployment_package):
        """
        Updates the code for a Lambda function by submitting a .zip archive that contains
        the code for the function.

        :param function_name: The name of the function to update.
        :param deployment_package: The function code to update, packaged as bytes in
                                   .zip format.
        :return: Data about the update, including the status.
        """
        try:
            response = self.lambda_client.update_function_code(
                FunctionName=function_name, ZipFile=deployment_package
            )
        except ClientError as err:
            logger.error(
                "Couldn't update function %s. Here's why: %s: %s",
                function_name,
                err.response["Error"]["Code"],
                err.response["Error"]["Message"],
            )
            raise
        else:
            return response
```

And then here is how it is used:

```
print(f"Let's update the function to an arithmetic calculator.")
q.ask("Press Enter when you're ready.")
print("Creating a new deployment package...")
deployment_package = wrapper.create_deployment_package(
    calculator_file, f"{lambda_name}.py"
)
print(f"...and updating the {lambda_name} Lambda function.")
update_waiter = UpdateFunctionWaiter(lambda_client)
wrapper.update_function_code(lambda_name, deployment_package)
update_waiter.wait(lambda_name)
```